# Splitting table and writing to multiple .txt files

Tags: r

I have a table in the following format.

```
Category    Value
Name_01 10
Name_01 12
Name_01 11
Name_02 12
Name_02 1
Name_03 13
Name_04 11
Name_05 12
Name_06 21
Name_07 3
Name_08 1
Name_09 23
Name_10 1
Name_11 123
Name_12 12
Name_13 1
Name_14 1
Name_15 12
Name_16 1
Name_17 2
Name_18 33
Name_19 21
Name_20 123
Name_21 32
Name_22 23
Name_23 21
```

I'd like to write the table to a .txt file but each .txt file can only handle a maximum of 20 unique categories. Therefore, the table would need to be split across multiple .txt files depending on the total number of categories. Does anybody know how I can do this using base R? The other complication is that all the .txt files must have categories numbered from 1-20. In the example below, I would have one .txt file containing names_01-20, and a second .txt file containing names_21-23 but renamed to names_01-03.

Comment: apologies, I've still not found a solution. does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# split 
myList <- 
  lapply(split(df1, as.numeric(df1$Category) %/% 21 + 1), 
         function(i){
           x <- i
           x$Category <- droplevels(x$Category)
           x$Category <- as.factor(as.numeric(x$Category))
           x
         })

# write to csv
lapply(names(myList), function(i) write.csv(myList[[ i ]], 
                                            file = paste0(i, ".csv"),
                                            row.names = FALSE))
```

This will output 2 files: *1.csv*, *2.csv*

Comment: thanks, apologies but I'm not sure how to use this to write my text files?

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried this and got the following error 'In split.default(seq_len(nrow(x)), f, drop) : NAs introduced by coercion (525 times)'

Comment: thanks, I have done, I haven't included all 525 rows though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155919/discussion-between-zx8754-and-ash-23s).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
maxCategory <- 20
N <- ceiling(1:nrow(data) / maxCategory)

for(i in unique(N)) {
    d <- data[N == i, ]
    # Get category with 0
    foo <- 1:nrow(d)
    foo <- ifelse(foo < 10, paste0("0", foo), foo) 
    d$Category <- paste0("Name_", foo)
    # Write text file
    write.table(d, paste0("split_", i, ".txt"),
                row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
```

Output files are: `split_1.txt` and `split_2.txt`. `split_2.txt` looks like this:

```
Category Value
Name_01 32
Name_02 23
Name_03 21
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I'm not sure this works as I may have multiple rows with the same Category value.

Comment: @Ash_23S you have to edit your question and provide example data, then I can adjust my code to that :-)

Comment: thanks, I've done that now. It doesn't matter how many rows there are in each .txt file, as long as there is a maximum of 20 unique categories.

Comment: thanks, that doesn't quite solve the problems. Each table is not restricted by the number of rows, but is restricted by the number of unique categories. Hence with the data above, the first txt file should contain rows 1-23, and the second should contain rows 23 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution.

```
library('magrittr')
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~Value,
    'Name_01',   10,
    'Name_02',   12,
    'Name_03',   13,
    'Name_04',   11,
    'Name_05',   12,
    'Name_06',   21,
    'Name_07',    3,
    'Name_08',    1,
    'Name_09',   23,
    'Name_10',    1,
    'Name_11',  123,
    'Name_12',   12,
    'Name_13',    1,
    'Name_14',    1,
    'Name_15',   12,
    'Name_16',    1,
    'Name_17',    2,
    'Name_18',   33,
    'Name_19',   21,
    'Name_20',  123,
    'Name_21',   32,
    'Name_22',   23,
    'Name_23',   21
)
```

First, we extract the Category IDs using `parse_number`. We use `dense_rank(Category)` to get a running distinct count of categories. We use this to increment the `group_id` every 20 distinct categories. We also create a `file_name` column based on the min/max `category_id` of the group.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    category_id = parse_number(Category),
    group_id = cumsum(dense_rank(Category) %% 20 == 1)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(file_name = stringr::str_c('names_', min(category_id), '-', max(category_id), '.txt'))

print(df2, n=100)
# # A tibble: 23 x 6
# # Groups:   group_id [2]
#    Category Value     g category_id group_id       file_name
#       <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <int>           <chr>
#  1  Name_01    10     1           1        1  names_1-20.txt
#  2  Name_02    12     1           2        1  names_1-20.txt
#  3  Name_03    13     1           3        1  names_1-20.txt
#  4  Name_04    11     1           4        1  names_1-20.txt
#  5  Name_05    12     1           5        1  names_1-20.txt
#  6  Name_06    21     1           6        1  names_1-20.txt
#  7  Name_07     3     2           7        1  names_1-20.txt
#  8  Name_08     1     2           8        1  names_1-20.txt
#  9  Name_09    23     2           9        1  names_1-20.txt
# 10  Name_10     1     2          10        1  names_1-20.txt
# 11  Name_11   123     2          11        1  names_1-20.txt
# 12  Name_12    12     2          12        1  names_1-20.txt
# 13  Name_13     1     2          13        1  names_1-20.txt
# 14  Name_14     1     3          14        1  names_1-20.txt
# 15  Name_15    12     3          15        1  names_1-20.txt
# 16  Name_16     1     3          16        1  names_1-20.txt
# 17  Name_17     2     3          17        1  names_1-20.txt
# 18  Name_18    33     3          18        1  names_1-20.txt
# 19  Name_19    21     3          19        1  names_1-20.txt
# 20  Name_20   123     3          20        1  names_1-20.txt
# 21  Name_21    32     3          21        2 names_21-23.txt
# 22  Name_22    23     3          22        2 names_21-23.txt
# 23  Name_23    21     3          23        2 names_21-23.txt
```

Now, we can `nest` the original columns into a list-column.

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(group_id, file_name) %>%
  nest(Category, Value)
print(df2, n=100)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   group_id       file_name              data
#      <int>           <chr>            <list>
# 1        1  names_1-20.txt <tibble [20 x 2]>
# 2        2 names_21-23.txt  <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Then we `walk` through each `data`+`file_name` pair and output each file using `write_delim`.

```
df2 %$%
  walk2(
    .$data,
    .$file_name,
    write_delim)
```

We can combine all the above steps into a single pipeline.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    category_id = parse_number(Category),
    group_id = cumsum(dense_rank(Category) %% 20 == 1)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(file_name = stringr::str_c('names_', min(category_id), '-', max(category_id), '.txt')) %>%
  group_by(group_id, file_name) %>%
  nest(Category, Value) %$%
  walk2(
    .$data,
    .$file_name,
    write_delim)
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help, but I do need a Base R solution as I can't use other packages in the software.